# Is it possible to git mv after push?

Tags: git

I did a *git mv* but for whatever reason after I pushed (multiple times) the file looks like it was deleted and there is a new file with the same name. Losing all of its history.

Is there a way to *git mv* after the push?

Comment: Are you working on a shared branch? Did you PR the branch yet? You'll probably have to redo it and force push...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git doesn't really track file moves.  When you move a file, git records it as a file at one path deleted, and a file at another path created.

The `git mv` command confuses a lot of users into believing that there is a way to actually record that a file moved, but there still is not; `git mv` is just an equivalent shorthand to moving the file with your OS (i.e. a shell command or drag-and-drop in windows) and then `add`ing the resulting changes.

Even though what's recorded is a delete and a create, many git commands do (by default) attempt to detect create/delete pairs that likely were really file moves.  This is why git sometimes reports that a file moved and/or tracks the file's history through a move.

There are a number of things that affect how rename detection works.  The most important one is that the file content not change too much in the commit where it moves — so it's often best, if practical, to do the move in a commit that leaves the file otherwise unchanged.  But, even then, rename detection isn't perfect, and in some circumstances it can really struggle.  (For example, a merge doesn't look at intermediate commits, so even if you're careful to always do renames in their own commit, a later merge may not see things correctly.)

Rename detection is not affected by whether you used `mv`, by whether you pushed, or by filename similarity; only the similarity of the content is considered.

Comment: ok, well that explains it. In my case, I moved file and changed the contents of the file quite a bit.